# DIV with border-radius but no border

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, rounded-corners

I have a div with `border-width: 0px;` and `border-radius: 5px;` (or `-moz-border-radius` etc.).

In Chrome, Safari and Firefox this works very well, the div gets rounded corners, so it is transparent in the corners.

IE9 however, does not display the rounded corners (I checked, IE is really in "IE9 mode", I have a HTML5 doctype and set `X-UA-Compatible` to `IE=edge`). It only does if I add

```
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
```

Can I get IE9 to render rounded corners without declaring an actual border?

Comment: I don't have IE to experiment with, but have you tried `overflow: hidden;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the div was filled with a gradient. Since IE9 does not support CSS gradients, I had to use

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#79D5FF', endColorstr='#08609A');
```

and this does not work with rounded corners, i.e., `border-radius` does not cut off the corners of the gradient.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `border-top-left-radius`, `border-top-right-radius` etc. for example? I've used something similar before for rounded corners on div's and it worked in IE9/Chrome/FF, not IE8 though.